# Multiple "and"s using Google Query

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to run multiple queries on a table using Google query.

I have been trying to sparse the dataset using the **a,b,c columns** using multiple criteria for each column using an `AND` combiner.

If one criterion is removed then I want the remaining criteria to be used but as Google query from what I can tell requires an `AND` between each match.

If I remove the criteria on one column I also need to remove the `AND` depending on which criteria I remove. Is it possible to wrap all my criteria in one `AND` request like `where AND (a matches 1000, b matches 11, c matches 44)`?

**Formula contained in the spreadsheet** (refer image below):

```
"QUERY(
$A$1:$D$7,
""select A,B,C,D 
where  
""&IF($A$10="""",,""A MATCHES '""&$A$10&""'AND"")&""
""&IF($B$10="""",,""B MATCHES '""&$B$10&""'"")&""
""&IF(AND($A$10<>"""",),,IF(AND(OR($A$10="""",$A$10<>""""),$B$10<>"""",$C$10<>""""),""AND"",)&""
""&IF($C$10="""",,""C MATCHES '""&$C$10&""'"")&""
""))"
```

**Image of the tables:**

[image: image of tables]

Here is a link to the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOTLqfLMgtU0F_T6TwjHkTAX2qecwH0FkOFY5ZDEmac/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Consider adding a sample screenshot, and editing your question to make it more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:D8,
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1,   
 IF(A11="",,"A matches '"&A11&"'"), 
 IF(B11="",,"B matches '"&B11&"'"),
 IF(C11="",,"C matches '"&C11&"'")))
```